# How to start Microsoft Word as a simple plain text editor

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, styles

As you may know, MS-Word have a predefined styles for Headings, Paragraphs, Capital letters and more stored into it's default template.

You may not want to use at all. Whenever you start your document you start re-defining those styles again, and some of those styles are nested from Normal style. All are included in a word template to use it more than time. I know I can change it once and save it into a new template. But that will include all used and unused styles and will keep the old styles that I didn't use, without mentioning MS-word settings: like bullets indentations and paragraphs spacing and auto editing correction.

My question is how to rest all predefined styles in the word template as if I am in a plain text editor for start defining my own styles independently: those I only want?

Who works with CSS frameworks knows what I am talking about. There is a CSS file with each framework to reset the browsers' predefined styles. And that's what I am looking for: a rest template for all predefined word styles.

Comment: only as a side note: since Win8 there is a also a kind-of-subset Word app in the MS App Store which is by far not that fat...

Comment: Have you tried deleting the styles you don't want from `normal.dotm`? You probably have to leave at least one style in place.

Comment: Thank you for your followup, actually some style couldn't be deleted and some software setting may prevent you doing so. not only for the styles but also for auto editing like automatic capital letters and bullets indentations and default paragraph spacing.